# Confusion about the shouldRedirectRLocked method (go1.11 src/net/http/server.go:2259)

Tags: http, go

I'm reading the source code about http module, and following code confused me:

```
func (mux *ServeMux) shouldRedirectRLocked(host, path string) bool {
    p := []string{path, host + path}

    for _, c := range p {
        if _, exist := mux.m[c]; exist {
            return false
        }
    }

    n := len(path)
    if n == 0 {
        return false
    }
    for _, c := range p {
        if _, exist := mux.m[c+"/"]; exist {
            return path[n-1] != '/' <<- why not return true directly
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

As the comment above this method: **shouldRedirectRLocked reports whether the given path and host should be redirected to path+"/". This should happen if a handler is registered for path+"/" but not path -- see comments at ServeMux.**

**c+"/"** already registered, and **c** didn't , so I think it should return true directly, but why we have to check **path[n - 1] != '/'**? Is this a question about the http protocol?

Comment: If `path` is, for example, `"/foo/bar/"` then `c+"/"` is `"/foo/bar//"`. So the check means: don't redirect to `path+"/"` if `path` already has a slash at the end.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you for your reply! But in the fact I can have a handler with pattern "/foo/bar//", and when I try to access "http://localhost:3000/foo/bar//", the browser(Chrome 68) 
 will delete the last slash, and becasur of the check, the shouldRedirectRLocked method return false, so I cannot access this handler anymore, is that means the path end with two slash is not a valid path?

Comment: I don't know whether it's valid or not, try googling "url rfc" and you should find your answer. Also try `curl localhost:3000/foo/bar//`, maybe curl doesn't remove the slash.